# Special replace in Sed

Tags: bash, replace, sed

How I can do to make the replacement of a line is only when it begins and ends only with a value. Example
I have these lines

```
Line 1: http_access allow acl1 acl2
Line 2: http_access deny acl1
```

I want to happen to thirst http_access deny me acl1 just remove the line 2. When using `sed 's/http_access deny acl1/mi_nueva_regla/g' /file` modifies me the two lines.

Comment: that doesn't seem right, double check your content.  Also, you don't need the `g` suffix, but that's not the issue.

Comment: The given `s///` command will change only one line.

Comment: Please include some sample input and expected output as part of your [mcve].  That will make it easier for others to reproduce and understand what you're seeing and improve your chances of a useful answer.

Comment: I don't understand "I want to happen to thirst http_access deny me acl1 just remove the line 2." What does thirst mean in this context?

Comment: For example I have Line 1: http_access allow acl1 acl2
Line 2: http_access deny acl1 Line 3: http_access allow acl2 acl3 Line 4: http_access deny acl1 acl3 I want deleted only the line 2, http_access deny acl1 and keep the rest of the file without changes.

Comment: How about `/deny/d`?

Answer (score 0):

Given an input file **file.txt**:

```
$ cat file.txt
http_access allow acl1 acl2
http_access deny acl1
http_access allow acl2 acl3
http_access deny acl1 acl3
```

To remove only first line containing `http_access deny` with GNU sed :

```
sed '0,/http_access deny/{/http_access deny/d}' file.txt
```

or shorter:

```
sed '0,/http_access deny/{//d}' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
http_access allow acl1 acl2
http_access allow acl2 acl3
http_access deny acl1 acl3
```

Comment: The `0` address is a GNU `sed` extension.